# Relationship between complexity classes XP and W[1]?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, parameterized-complexity

I am reading the introductory chapter in [Parameterized Algorithms](http://parameterized-algorithms.mimuw.edu.pl/) by Cygan *et al.* and I am having some problems with the distinction between complexity classes $\mathsf{W[1]}$ and $\mathsf{XP}$.

They explicitly define complexity class $\mathsf{XP}$ on p. 13 as the those problems that, given an instance $(x, k)$ of a parameterized problem, can be correctly decided by an algorithm in $O(f(k)\cdot|(x,k)|^{g(k)})$ time for functions $g, k$. I believe I understand this.

Complexity class $\mathsf{W[1]}$ is not explicitly defined. However, in the discussion of $k$-cliques on p. 9, they give an $O(n^k)$ algorithm for deciding whether a $k$-clique exists in a graph. As I understand it, therefore, the $k$-clique problem must be in $\mathsf{XP}$. However, the authors discuss it as a $\mathsf{W[1]}$ problem in a way that I find confusing.

My question, then, is twofold: (1) **Am I right in thinking that $\mathsf{W[1]} \subseteq \mathsf{XP}$**? I haven't been able to settle this by looking ahead in the book or by searching online. (2) **Intuitively, what is the difference between the two classes?** I have found defitions online, e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity), but not in language that I have found accessible. I would appreciate, therefore, if someone could provide more of an overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, you are right: W[1] is a subset of XP. As you noticed, $k$-clique is in XP. The class W[1] is (usually by definition) the closure of that problem under FPT-reductions. XP is closed under these reductions. Hence the subsetship.

2) Citing [another answer of mine](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/91398), here is a bit of intuition about XP:

> The practical importance of XP is as a door to parameterized
>   complexity analysis. Once a problem is recognized as belonging to XP
>   it makes sense to investigate its exact parameterized complexity. If
>   it does not even belong to XP, parameterized analysis doesn't make
>   much sense. It can also be argued that in that case the
>   parameterization is not meaningful.

In that sense, XP is the hardest intractable class of parameterized complexity theory. In an even fuzzier sense, on the very opposite side of the spectrum, W[1] is the easiest parameterized version of NP.

Gaining an intuition for W[1] is not exactly made easy (in the past I tried in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/91440)). As said, it is usually defined by completeness of a problem (like $k$-clique). Definitions using machine models exist (e.g. Chen, Flum, Grohe: Machine-based methods in parameterized complexity theory. TCS 339(2-3), 2005). But that does not imply they are suitable for entry-level understanding of the class. I suggest you just take W[1] as the sum of the facts you know about it.